# WP Admin/ WP Login Redirect to themselves

Tags: wp-admin, login

Today I tried to reach my back office and I simply couldn't. `Wp-admin` redirected to `wp-login` and `wp-login` keeps redirecting to itself.

Here's what I've tried:

- Delete `.htaccess`
- replace my `wp-admin` folder with an older version from last-month
- Clear cache and cookies
- Try all common browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome)

Anybody got any hints into fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some file can be corrupted. I suggest you to replace also wp-includes folder and wp-settings.php. After this let me know if it works.
Thanks,
Monica